# Autohotkey high priority remapping

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remapping

I want to make RCtrl+(w/a/s/d) map to (up/left/down/right), I wrote this script:

```
$>^w::Send {Up Down}
$>^w Up::Send {Up Up}

$>^a::Send {Left Down}
$>^a Up::Send {Left Up}

$>^s::Send {Down Down}
$>^s Up::Send {Down Up}

$>^d::Send {Right Down}
$>^d Up::Send {Right Up}
```

the problem is that it won't works with combination:

when I pressdown {shift} and use {RCtrl}+d, I hope I can select the text just as {Shift}+{Right}, but I find it is hard to do, using the wildcard also not working.

Is any method like below to make it work?

```
*$>^w::Send *{Up Down}
*$>^w Up::Send *{Up Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use some dumb method to do this(if some day I want it support ctrl, I'll add some more remapping script):

```
*$>^+w::Send +{Up Down}
*$>^+w Up::Send +{Up Up}
*$>^+a::Send +{Left Down}
*$>^+a Up::Send +{Left Up}
*$>^+s::Send +{Down Down}
*$>^+s Up::Send +{Down Up}
*$>^+d::Send +{Right Down}
*$>^+d Up::Send +{Right Up}

*$>^w::Send {Up Down}
*$>^w Up::Send {Up Up}
*$>^a::Send {Left Down}
*$>^a Up::Send {Left Up}
*$>^s::Send {Down Down}
*$>^s Up::Send {Down Up}
*$>^d::Send {Right Down}
*$>^d Up::Send {Right Up}
```